# Возможно ли русифицировать Dev Tools Chrome?

Tags: c++, google-chrome

Как можно русифицировать инструменты разработчика (Dev Tools) в браузере Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Да (в теории).

Строки UI DevTools обернуты в вызов функции `Common.UIString`, например https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/elements/ElementsPanel.js?l=49

```
this._searchableView.setPlaceholder(Common.UIString('Find by string, selector, or XPath'));
```

В свою очередь UIString использует Common.localize - https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/common/UIString.js?l=47

```
Common.localize = function(string) {
  return string;
};
```

Т.е. можно переписать Common.localize так, чтобы она подменяла строки на локализованные и пересобрать хромиум.